# Animate view inside OnClick

Tags: java, android, onclick

If I try to animate `view` inside `OnClick`, it doesn't work:

```
myImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        view.setAlpha(0.5f); //This works

        view.animate().scaleX(0.5f).setDuration(300).setInterpolator(
            new BounceInterpolator()).withLayer(); //This doesn't work
    }
});
```

In this code, `setAlpha` works correctly, but `animate()` doesn't.

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: there are many ways to animate, but the first thing I notice is that you do not call `start()`

Comment: @Jim it's the same thing, even if I call start().

Comment: does your BounceInterpolator() need more specification?

Answer (score 0):

First, you never called `start()` on the animation you have set up. It's not enough to call `animate()` -- that just gives you the `ViewPropertyAnimator` for that view -- you also have to start it.

```
view.animate()
        .scaleX(0.5f)
        ...
        .start();
```

Second, be aware that after the first click, any further clicks will appear to do nothing because the properties you are animating are already at the desired end values.

Comment: regardless that I call `start()` animation never occurs, nor the first time.

Comment: Actually no need to write start() It should still work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mImageView.animate().setAlpha(0.5f).scaleX(0.5f).setDuration(300).setInterpolator(
            new BounceInterpolator()).start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope, that's the same.